# What are these elements in my array and how can I get rid of them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, chart.js

I am trying to visualize data from a mysql database in chartjs.
I want to show how many times a certain number (1-6) occurs in the dataset I selected.

I've managed to get a nice array, but entries from ": Array []" are messing with my efforts.

Relevant php:

```
  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();

  $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

  foreach ($result as $row) {
     # code...
     $output[] = $row;
}
  print json_encode(array_count_values($output));
```

Relevant js:

```
var obj = $.ajax({
  url : "https://localhost/auswertung/data1.php",
  type : "GET",
  success : function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
  })


var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return [Number(key), obj[key]];
});
```

When I look at the console output in firefox, I see this:

```
   {…}
1: 2
2: 1
3: 1
<prototype>: {…}
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()
constructor: function Object()
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
toSource: function toSource()
toString: function toString()
valueOf: function valueOf()
```

And my table looks like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywmwY.png)

What am I missing?

Comment: You appear to be logging a lot more than just `data` to your console? Have you got some more console.log commands somewhere? And what do you mean by " entries from ": Array []""...I don't see that phrase in your output, or in your code.

Comment: Methods and properties of the [`Object` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). What you have is an object and not an array.

Comment: Your logging the entire Object, all Objects have a prototype. Those are your objects prototype methods

Comment: BTW It's not clear why you're mapping `obj`? `obj` is not your response data, it's a jQuery Deferred object (as it clear from the $.ajax documentation). The response data is returned to you in the `data` object in your "success" callback (which you already know because you're logging it to your console. If you want to count the occurrences of things in the data, it's that `data` var you need to be  working with. You need to parse it as JSON (but beware, your PHP output appears to have a stray newline at the start, you might want to fix that) and then process it.

Comment: Thank you all, that was already quite helpful in understanding my problem.

So I need to parse the json inside the $.ajax in order to do anything useful with it. ADyson, do you have any hints as to how to go about this in order to feed chartjs with usable data? And where do you see the newline in the PHP output?

Comment: After some time of banging my head to the wall, I actually almost got it to work. Following the hints of @ADyson I managed to get at least a semi-working graph. So for posterity, see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933309/chartjs-only-displays-first-element-of-array)

Comment: You have to do use `JSON.parse()` to parse a string into JSON. The newline is shown if you visit your page in a browser and look at the response in the Network tab. The actual data doesn't appear until line 2. Sadly the link you originally posted (still visible in the edit history) doesn't work anymore, so I can't double-check that, but that's what I remember seeing.